power bi , make a segment that combine 2 columns of 2 tables
I have table A that has column productA and table B has productB :
 in productA  there's prod1, prod 2, prod3 .
 in productB , there's prod1, prod2, prod3, prod4.

I want to make a segment that present the graphics per product but the problem is the segment show only the commun product(i cant present product4).
How to do to that segment able to present all  the products and its graphes?

Can you share your model?

maybe you can try this in power query.

make sure the column names in both tables are the same (case sensitive)

create a new column in Product A table
="Product A"


create a similar column in Product B table




append both table



